# Responsive matrix3D transformation

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to create responsive layout for my project where i have `png` image as a background and `jpg` screenshot for screen area. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/350D/7Lmxcc2L/) on JSFiddle. I've created `matrix3D` transformation [here](http://www.useragentman.com/matrix/#E4UwziAuBCCumQPYDsBMBeASuKACAYosALYBkAZsIsQAwAe6NFVtAno6UvegBw+eIa7VAFYAbM2oBGdlNQ8mSKQwDsYlQJnoVKppWqpVqRYkPoRU-klTsALCIEBmBnJpXEjuwE4NAEw8AIuiQwLAgpACWvlLoAMqwAEbEEZCRvhjYEKkAFpDEADYAwiiQIMiQ6KQAxmBgxeVlFQD0AFQAULgtBCAg+biUPbhIuCC+KbgAhsisuIjkQ9kguGCQrPnguAm9iADuAHQdLU1tba0jyGCwoJP5fZCLI+vEjWDLq+u+m9s7uLAQm0RfCBgABaBKIOidY57BL5RBVADWABpcABiADmwCiuAA3h1cATwXQQWAIgAvCLIdEALgBwCBoKJAG42gBfE5nAAqD0QCQAViAqpAvuQiEtxhFXiEpmBRSRRlC2qjEFJcfjCRNEZjELBkL5aajyOQqiaqiz2acutylryBULJuRSsBcONshNXlsykNgDK5c9PkclaY1QSNVqqLr9WjTVUjeaOV1isRiCg3msNnKAZDbYLIGA9oqYXDESHQ6LyiTySBaZTFljIObcAncIVYrF+kQFktMdjAxisZ88aHNpqEdrI7SrvkABQAIgixAm6PATQSo-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) using fixed image sizes for background and screenshot images. As you can see — image perfectly aligned and `transform-origin` set to `0` and this transformation applied:

`transform: matrix3d( 0.642387, -0.289132, 0, 0.000087, 0.456665, 0.32747, 0, -0.000096, 0, 0, 1, 0, 88, 256, 0, 1);`

[image]

Now i'm trying to make it responsive to screen width but i can't figured it out to how fix incorrect proportions on smaller screen size or any other than close to original one (try to resize the JSFiddle window) that was used to create `matrix3d` transformation.

[image]

Looks like `matrix3d` linked to element dimensions in pixels or maybe i'm wrong.

UPDATE #1:

I have some progress here by trying to eliminate `translate` part from `matrix3d`. I've moved `transform-origin` to 50% 50% too to make sure that all transformations applied in same way from the center of the image. [Here is](http://www.useragentman.com/matrix/#E4UwziAuBCCumQPYDsBMBeASuKACAYosALYBkAZsIsQAwAe6AtAMwBsNFVtAnk6wCwck9JgFZ+zUsN6MAjLIAcnarN4ChiWQ1nNRUzb2YBOVsuKoGbDRabzU+1DOaolSZg1EB2I-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-JJwa1A6YA6aVEaUKAEdIPw5qUAG5GbjkZj8DpxFeFFAgVAnFd6QAfm3ABSZhEgASlwRhWGYWQVzhFhPH4RDcGQRBGFAFcQDmVseknGMDSNOtqQbXAdFQVA0IUIxREQzko1wFdECpSA4hQJlQFKPC4kfEBGKjRB+OAchkSOJlHzlOIkQEnpdldJl2BoBieiQFcGUEFS6BTMNZC1AipxnI052ARdlzXDctx3PdEAPWEjxPM9hTiOhiGvYVSkA4VFiNYAOmLRAcUwr8f2QEBQNQGhIoUVBIqME5hRXHEQNKcCoNwGhMvQzDsNwiUAEI4mIFjgEgBZ8MI6dYxIqkyKZY8RNwIqSqIcrak5bkwwjYk7N1LJuCZE4FE5KrjONeclwQSzN23Xd90PY9iFPDoXLcjyvOQHzuD8gKwCCkLv1-SLopcOLUASpKUrAiDZGg0RouyjCsJAHC8NGoyaqCUiG0ayFOQVO4g0YIg4hxOkmSymhOq5HJmBSdJMglAAJPkAFkABl5iNTtuxyfh0HKBYGmGHJRHQBpkQgHJWApqmQCAA) the updated toolkit state and [new JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/350D/0r8vnd9u/). Still not perfect.

UPDATE #2:

I've created simple UI to control all rotate/scale transformation [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/350D/t11sbzv4/) and recropped iPhone image to make sure that center of the green screen (you can see cross lines in the middle) is in the same location as a screenshot center; Now i have more controls and more predictable results but still have problems with resizing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've implemented a perspective correction on `window.resize` and this is a solution in my case. [Here is a final JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/350D/qgzb4j35/). Still don't get the point how it helps but it works fine.